# version control Stylus Studio XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt

How do you version control using Stylus Studio?

I read we can use GIT HUB for Oxygen, but we use Stylus and I wanted to know how others handle it?.

Answer (score 0):

In Stylus Studio itself you can't. I suggest you use an external SVN or Git client.